# issue in creating amazon queue with AWS4C lib

Tags: web, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws4c

I am using AWS4C library and trying to create a simple queue at Amazon.

Due to some reason, it's failing to make a queue. I debugged the URL, which is posted to the server and it looks fine. Sample URL is :

http://queue.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListQueues&QueueNamePrefix=AWS-SQS-Sample&AWSAccessKeyId=NABEEL34D&Signature=o%2BGSj3DFt8h8g5QP4uQlgI%2B%2Fd%2Bk%3D&SignatureVersion=1&Timestamp=2014-04-22T20:55:26Z&Version=2009-02-01

I guess that u also need to set region parameter. But I could not find that information anywhere in AWS4C library code . .

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing AWS4C might have the old request format that may not supported anymore (I haven't tried).

You can try something like this:

```
http://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123456789012/queue1?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Your%20Message%20Text​&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Version=2012-11-05​&Expires=2008-02-10T12:00:00Z​&Signature=lBP67vCvGlDMBQ1do​fZxg8E8SUEXAMPLE&SignatureVersion=2&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
```

For making a request to the `us-east-1` SQS region.  You can see more information in the latest docs here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MakingRequests_MakingQueryRequestsArticle.html